# How to add field programmatically to list (without adding it to CT)

Tags: 2007, development

I'm adding here a field to the list, but it adds itself to a default content type, how can I add it to library but not to CT?

```
            SPFieldBoolean flagField = (SPFieldBoolean)library.Fields.CreateNewField(SPFieldType.Boolean.ToString(), "flagfield");
            flagField.DefaultValue = "0";
            library.Fields.Add(flagField);
            library.Update();
```

Comment: Do you have multiple CTs in the library?

Comment: yes, it has multiple CT's and it adds to the default one, but i just want it to be added to the document library!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question!
[Here is the answer.](http://spfromigo.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/add-spfield-to-not-default-contenttype/)